# How to properly create numpy string arrays using the NumPY C API

Tags: python, c, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array of strings in a C extension module.  I cant tell what im doing wrong, I've tried various things at this point.  My main issue is that im creating a fixed-size string type array, where the fixed size is effectively the max size but the strings are null-terminated c strings.
The problem is that when I print out the array ive returned, it prints the entire fixed length rather than respecting the null terminator, ie:

> b'PZYJKT\x00A\x04' b'PZYJKBT\x00\x04' b'PZYJKBT\x00\x04'

rather than

> b'PZYJKT' b'PZYJKBT' b'PZYJKBT'

I set the dtype in this example = "S13".  If I do the same thing in native python, everything works fine:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array( [ 'PZYJKT', 'PZYJKBT', 'PZYJKBT' ], dtype = 'S13' )
array([b'PZYJKT', b'PZYJKBT', b'PZYJKBT'], dtype='|S13')
```

even though internally it seems to be represented just like my string array:

```
>>> _.tobytes()
b'PZYJKT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PZYJKBT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PZYJKBT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

The only thing I just noticed is that if i zero init the entire fixed string, then it seems to work similar to python.   Could it be that numpy looks at the entire string for the *last* null-terminator?

EDIT: Code im using to create the array:

```
template<size_t N>
PyObject * as_nparray( char * data )
{
    npy_intp dims[1]{ ( npy_intp ) buffer.size() };

    bp::str date_type = ( "S"s + std::to_string( N ) ).c_str();
    PyArray_Descr *descr;
    PyArray_DescrConverter( date_type.ptr(), &descr );
    return PyArray_NewFromDescr( &PyArray_Type, descr, 1, dims, NULL, data, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA, NULL );
}
```

I'll also add that I found this post which seems to imply my suspicion that numpy strings are expected to be null *padded* rather than null terminated:
https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2014-July/070637.html

Comment: Could you add the (minimized) code that "creates the numpy array of strings in a C extension module" and gives you the wrong result?

Comment: This looks like C++ code, it would be better if you replace the `c` tag of your question with the `c++` tag. Then your question will appear in the correct filter.

Comment: sorry, but that's not some code that can be executed without having your GrowingBuffer. Could you include a [mcve]?